# Fullcalendar Dynamic Event Color Through MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, events, colors, fullcalendar

this is my first post, so be gentle :)

I am brand new to PHP, MySQL, and JQUERY, but I have a lot of experience programming with AS3, Java, and C++, so I have some frame of reference to how some of this stuff works...

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- I am creating a website for my church and using the Fullcalendar class for our scheduler
- Note: Google Calendar is not an option
- I need to be able to set recurring events, and color each event based on whether or not it has been canceled

Here's how far I've gotten:

- I have a MySQL database with 8 fields: p_id (for my use only), id, title, start, end, allDay, url, canceled
- I have a PHP file with the following code:

.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Example php script for fetching data from mysql database
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$host = "fakehost";
$user = "fakeuser";
$pass = "fakepwd";

$databaseName = "fake_db";
$tableName = "tbl_calendar";

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1) Connect to mysql database
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2) Query database for data
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$query = "SELECT id,title,start, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' ) AS startDate, end, url FROM $tableName ORDER BY startDate DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$array[] = $row; 
}  

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 3) echo result as json 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

- I also have the following code in my HTML file:

  ```
  <script type='text/javascript'>

  $(document).ready(function() {

  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      editable: false,

      allDayDefault: false,

      url: true,

      timeFormat: 'h(:mm)t', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
      agenda: 'h(:mm)t' , // 5:00 - 6:30
      '': 'h(:mm)t', // for all other views

      events: "../data/get_calendar.php",
      eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
          alert(event.title + ' ha sido movido ' + delta + ' dias\n' + '(should probably update your database)');

      },

      loading: function(bool) {
          if (bool) $('#loading').show();
          else $('#loading').hide();
      },

      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

           //alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
           //alert('Url: ' + calEvent.url);
           //alert('View: ' + view.name);

           window.open(calEvent.url, blank);
           return false;

      }

  });


  });
  ```

It all works great as far as using the events I have in the database and placing them on the calendar where they belong.

The problem is that I'm trying to add specific CSS classes to each event.  I would like canceled events to be Red, for example (versus deleting them).

I have looked through a lot of material.  Read a lot about event sources and I just don't get it... I can't make it work.  Ideally, I'd like to add another field to my database and just have it apply a class name or color automatically.  I can apply colors through hard code, but I just don't understand how to do it through the database.

Can anyone help?  Please give me a lot of simple steps, because apparently, I'm not that smart :-S

**EDIT:**
I have tried to add a field called "className" and I've written corresponding CSS rules.  I thought that would do it, but when I inspect the element, I don't see the className anywhere... I don't think it's applying it automatically from the MySQL database.  I also tried Brotherli's suggestion below, but can't get that to work either (probably user error).  Perhaps I need to change some of my fullcalendar jquery code?

Comment: $query = "SELECT id,title,start, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' ) AS startDate, end, url FROM $tableName ORDER BY startDate DESC"; why are you not including 'Canceled' in this query. You should do it to use value of 'canceled' if false make background-color of your row or where-ever you are fetching it(I could not get it) as red

Comment: You are echo-ing(writing/displaying) your record using php and jquery on a web page from database. right? Delete some comments. As we are not allowed to chat much.

Comment: Yes, the end of my php file does this: echo json_encode($array);
The html file imports it using this line: 
events: "../data/get_calendar.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define CSS classes on a per-event basis. See attribute 'className' in http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Change your PHP code to something like

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if ($row['deleted'])
        $row['className'][] = 'deleted';
    if ($row['canceled'])
        $row['className'][] = 'canceled';
    $array[] = $row; 
}
```

Alternatively you can also add CSS classes on the client using the [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) callback.

Comment: Hey Brotherli - can you explain the logical test to me?
Ex: if ($row['canceled'])
What is it testing here?  A 'true' from the 'canceled' field?

Comment: Also, I've read the link you sent me a billion times... I get the concept of className (I've written CSS rules), but when I inspect the ID of a given event, I don't see the class name that should be there.  I also tried just adding a field called className to my database, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks Brotherli - I ended up using the eventRender callback and applied a className that way.

Comment: I'm glad you found your way with the eventRender callback. Just for the record and to answer your first question about the attributes testing of the mysql rows: please read the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) about implicit conversions to boolean values.